# Django Rest Framework - Import CSV(" No file was submitted ")

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am trying to upload CSV file in Django Rest Framework using the serializer.

Below have provides the image which contains code for Model, View, and Serializer and the console output when I try to submit the CSV file.

Before validating a serializer when I check with print(serializer.initial_data) there is a file inside the serializer, but as soon as the serializer is validating it says no file was submitted.

models.py

```
class InventoryFile(models.Model):
    shop           = models.ForeignKey(Shop,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    shop_inventory = models.FileField(upload_to='inventory/')
```

serializers.py

```
class InventoryFile_Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = InventoryFile
        fields = ('shop_inventory',)
```

views.py

```
class InvertoryUpload(APIView):
    serializer_class = InventoryFile_Serializer
    parser_classes = [ MultiPartParser,FormParser ]

    def post(self,request):
        try:
            serializer = InventoryFile_Serializer(data=request.data)
            print(serializer.initial_data)

            if serializer.is_valid():
                print(serializer.data)
                return Response("Done")
            else:
                print(serializer.errors)
                return Response("Not Done")

        except Exception as e:
            return Response(str(e))
```

Output

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
January 30, 2019 - 11:22:06
Django version 2.1, using settings 'hoplet.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
<QueryDict: {'inventory': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: MOCK_DATA_2.csv (application/vnd.ms-excel)>]}>
{'shop_inventory': [ErrorDetail(string='No file was submitted.', code='required')]}
[30/Jan/2019 11:22:18] "POST /uploadinv HTTP/1.1" 200 10
```

Comment: Please add code as text into the question instead of images.
it will help other SO users to search and benefit.

Comment: @TalhaJunaid Done. Thanks for correction.

Comment: @ChangeSierraJonathan the key name of the file in request is `inventory` and the key name that the serializer is looking for is `shop_inventory`. They should be the same. Change one of them and it should work.

Comment: @DavitTovmasyan Yes it did. I wasn't able to spot it , Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key name of the file in request is `inventory` and the key name that the serializer is looking for `is shop_inventory`. They should be the same. Change one of them and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
Please try in this way        

urls.py
              urlpatterns = [
            url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
            url(r'^upload_file', InvertoryUpload.as_view())

        ]

        models.py

        class InventoryFile(models.Model):
            shop = models.ForeignKey(Shop,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
            shop_inventory = models.FileField(upload_to='inventory/')


        views.py

        from rest_framework.parsers import MultiPartParser, FormParser
        from rest_framework.generics import CreateAPIView

        class InvertoryUpload(CreateAPIView):
            serializer_class = InventoryFile_Serializer
            parser_classes = [ MultiPartParser, FormParser ]

        serializers.py

        class InventoryFile_Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

            class Meta:
                model = InventoryFile
                fields = ('shop_inventory','shop')
```